# Какой язык программирования и приложения используются для создания модов Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft

Хочу разобраться, как создавать моды на Minecraft. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам под Forge или Fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используется Java. [Вот отличный курс по созданию модов для minecraft 1.15.](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCicAXLV4w2X6bn2EuM4To4w)
Плюс советую поучить сам язык программирования. На YouTube куча уроков о java.

Comment: огромное спасибо!